# How can I connect submitted form data with specific page using phpMyAdmin and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, phpmyadmin

I have a client who wants to have a comment box on each page of her website. The thing is, the website has already been created as a static html site. I've made comment boxes in the past using php and phpMyAdmin, and obviously I'll change each of her pages to .php instead of .html so it'll support my comment box's php code, but I've only ever created comment boxes for a single page before. The website I'm altering now has at least 10 pages that need a comment box, and more will be added in the future.

I like the idea of using a singular database table for all the comments that are submitted on the site (there won't be a high volume). I'm just not sure how to tell the submitted comment which page it's supposed to display on.

I think what I need to do is have the submitted comment store what page it's from in the database, and then I can have a function on each page that looks for all the comments with that particular page's name or id. I'm just not sure how to do the first part where I send in data that identifies the page with the rest of the comment box's data, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Sorry if this a silly question, I'm still pretty new at PHP, thanks!!

Comment: Please add code or attempts at getting your idea to work. This is a required minimal as stated in the rules of SO.

Comment: Please note for future reference that MySQL is the database, not PHPMyAdmin: the latter is simply a PHP-scripted client program for the MySQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're on the right track with your idea. There are multiple ways of doing it, but a simple solution would be to have a page name field in your database table. when gathering the information for db insertion retrieve the page by putting a hidden field in the comments form, maybe something like...

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_name" value="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" />
```

then upon fetching comments from the database do a db query like

```
"SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `page_name` = '".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."'";
```

Always remember to sanitize user information before db insertion!

Answer (score 0):

Whay you need is a tablewith a column that identifies the page you need. For instance:

Table: Comments

```
---------------------------------
id | page | comment | createdAt |
---------------------------------
1  |   1  |  Com1   | 2014-01-01 00:00:00|
2  |   2  |  Com2   | 2014-01-01 00:00:22|
3  |   1  |  Com3   | 2014-01-01 00:30:00|
4  |   1  |  Com4   | 2014-01-01 00:35:00|
```

Then at the specific page use the column page in your where clause to select only the comments from that page.

For instance:

```
SELECT comment, createdAt FROM comments WHERE page  = '1' ORDER BY createdAt DESC
```

The ORDER BY will rearrange the order with the newest on top.

When posting to the database insert the page identifier aswell.

```
INSERT INTO comments (page, comment, createdAt) VALUES ('1','this is a comment', NOW())
```

Get it?